# Graph Theory Critical Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So I have an exam coming up, my review sheet has a few questions on critical graph. Can I have some help with these questions please?

Definitions: A subgraph $H$ of $G$ is a $\underline{critical \ subgraph}$ if $\chi(G)=\chi(H)$ but removing any edge or vertex from $H$ results in a graph with lower chromatic number. A graph is $\underline{critical}$ if it's a critical subgraph for some graph.

(1) Suppose $H$ is a critical graph with $\chi(H)=4$. How many vertices of degree 1 can $H$ have. Explain. How many vertices of degree $2$?

(2) Suppose $H$ is a critical graph with $\chi(H)=5$. How many vertices of degree 2 can $H$ have. Explain. How many vertices of degree $3$?

(3) Generalize the previous two questions. That is if $H$ is critical what's the relation between $\chi(H)$ and minimum degree $H$?

For (1) and (2) do I add on new vertices and show that these vertices can be colored using any of the k colors other that the colors used by its neighbors? Or...

(1) and (2) this is not possible (I think) because the minimal degree of a critical graph seems to be at least k-1?

Answer (score 3):

If $‎\chi‎ (H)=k$, then $‎\delta‎ (H)‎\geq‎‎ k-1$.

Because if there exists a vertex $v$ such that $d(v)<k-1$, then we can remove the vertex $v$ and from criticality we can color vertices by $k-1$ colors. But for $v$ we have at least one  color. So we can color $H$ by $k-1$ colors, a contradiction.

So in general we have $\delta‎ (H)‎‎\geq‎ \chi‎ (H)-1$

Comment: Thanks. So I was pretty close with my reasoning?

Comment: Yes. You were right. I just explain your idea in a complete way.